# _tableView reloadData not working when i called method from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This table view is working fine when tableview is firstly loaded
but when I tried to reload data using `[_tableView reloadData]`, suddenly list won't reload at all.

Here's code:

```
-(void)loadListLoop{

    AppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    shuffleLbl.hidden=false;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:shuffleLbl];
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString*playlistID=delegate.gPlaylistID;
    NSString*token=[ud stringForKey:@"youtube_token"];


    NSString *origin = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=%@&key=AIzaSyBeFK_llQHRl7TyXoQxGkLDmIfKGzOPezM&access_token=%@",playlistID,token];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:origin]];
    NSData *json = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    _titleList=[array valueForKeyPath:@"items.snippet.title"];
    _thumbnailList=[array valueForKeyPath:@"items.snippet.thumbnails.default.url"];
    _idList=[array valueForKeyPath:@"items.snippet.resourceId.videoId"];
    NSLog(@"%@",_titleList);

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

The method `loadListLoop` is called from another class using:

```
PlaylistDetailViewController *playlistDetail = [[PlaylistDetailViewController alloc] init];
[playlistDetail loadList];
```

Looks like `loadListLoop` is successfully called and everything before `[_tableView reloadData];` is also successfully loaded.

I put NSLog inside `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
to see is app is at least trying to reload data but it seems its not working at all.

EDIT:
first,view controller that contains "-(void)loadListLoop" is container view.so target view controller should be on screen

EDIT2:
i defined outlet at .h file below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlaylistDetailViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    //IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *shuffleLbl;
}
-(void)exitLoopVoid;
-(void)loadListLoop;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *titleList;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *authorList;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *thumbnailList;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *idList;

-(IBAction)shuffle;

@end
```

*IMPORTANT*

**EDIT3:**
looks like some thing very weird is happening to NSMutableArray.

1. overwrite NSMutableArray at loadListLoop method(works fine and checked content with NSLog)
2. reload table(seems this is working fine too)
3. content inside NSMutableArray will rollback to old content

anyone has idea about this issue?

EDIT4:

1.overwrite NSMutableArray at loadListLoop method(success)
2.reload table and NSMutableArray will be null only at this method
3.rollback to data that i overwrites data at loadListLoop

Comment: Why are you using `dispatch_sync()` instead of `dispatch_async()`? Is it possible that the `tableView` is waiting for the main queue to finish and it doesn't happen? Also, is the table view really connected with the `_tableView` ivar? Did you try forcing the association with `@synthesize yourTableViewOutlet = _tableView;`? Try putting your `NSLog()`right after the `reloadData` method inside the block.

Comment: >>Try putting your NSLog()right after the reloadData  I tried, and the log has been outputted

Comment: Could you see if `_tableView` is actually not `nil`? `NSLog(@"%@", _tableView);` should not print `(null)`. It would be better if you include some more of your code... like where are you defining the outlet and the basic stuff of the class (the common methods, etc.)

Comment: yeah _tableview is not nil.

Comment: But did you connect the outlet from the Storyboard? Ctrl-Drag? Also connected the data source in the Storyboard?

Comment: yes i already connected outlet from storyboard

Comment: This is a long shot, but... did you try setting your `NSMutableArray` property as `(nonatomic, strong)` instead of `(nonatomic, retain)`? ARC uses `strong` as a retained and autoreleased object when all strong references are gone. I think (but not completely sure) that `retain` property modifiers are deprecated with ARC. EDIT: And `assign` for non-object elements like primitive types. I know `strong` and `retain` are supposed to be synonyms, but anyway, almost all Apple examples use `strong` nowadays.

Comment: As you're saving inside `NSMutableArray`s, you could save a `mutableCopy` of your elements (`valueForKeyPath:` should return a non-mutable version). What about `_titleList= [[array valueForKeyPath:@"items.snippet.title"] mutableCopy];` and so on? That "rollback" sounds weird it should always replace the object in the property if you're updating from the webservice. It could be the cache too... `NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:origin]
      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
      timeoutInterval:5.0];`

Comment: hmm rollback now just fixed but now reloading table view stopped working again..

Comment: How is your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method defined?

Comment: `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_titleList count];
}`

Comment: updated. plz check EDIT4

Comment: Oh, BTW... are you checking the `NSError` that the JSON serialization could be throwing? `NSError *jsonError = nil; NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:json options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError]; if ( jsonError ) { NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", [jsonError description]); }`

Comment: where do i should put that?

Comment: Where your NSJSONSerialization is.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems.

First, the code you posted is a method `loadListLoop`. But the code that you posted is calling a different method `loadList`. The two are not connected.

Second, you say:

the method "loadListLoop" is called from another class using

```
PlaylistDetailViewController *playlistDetail = 
  [[PlaylistDetailViewController alloc] init];
[playlistDetail loadList];
```

That code is very wrong. It is creating a brand new instance of PlaylistDetailViewController that is not on-screen, and invoking the `loadList` method on that newly created view controller.

The view controller hasn't had a chance to display itself yet, so it's view properties will be nil. Plus, the view controller probably doesn't have any data in the model structure it uses to populate it's table view, so it won't have anything to display.

Further, if your view controller's view structure is defined in a storyboard, you can't use alloc/init to create new view controller instances.

At the point where you're trying to call loadList/loadListLoop, is the target view controller on screen? You need to explain your calling sequence.

Answer (score 1):

use NSNotificationCenter for Update the table from one class to another class
1.do this in from where you have to call.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"UpdateTable" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

2.And use this one for table view class. Write this in ViewDidLoad method.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(refresh_method) 
    name:@"UpdateTable"
    object:nil];
```

3.

```
-(void)refresh_method        
{      
             //reload table here.   
}
```